# Driving a Servo a Motor

Tags: motor, servo

I want to drive a servo rc motor I just purchased, I am a newbie in the electronics world.

I would just like to test out the servo motor first and actually get it to move.

So far I have figured out I need a basic diagram for the circuit, I have consulted the servo motor data sheet, I know I need an oscillator, some transistors, a breadboard and a micro controller, not sure what else yet.

It is possible to drive it without a micro controller right?

I will be using the amicus micro controller.

Any suggestions?

Comment: A MCU will make it *so* much easier. Especially if the MCU supports PWM in hardware.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams  Generating control signals for the R/C servos with a hardware PWM is [arguably] an overkill.

Comment: @NickAlexeev: Then why is `analogWrite()` so popular?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams  I don't know why.  I don't even know if it is actually popular (being an Arduino function).  I was talking about R/C servo control signals.  You could have as well asked "why +12V is so popular". ;)

Answer (score 2):

It is possible. You need to generate a square wave. To change the angle of the servo, you should be able to adjust the pulse width of the wave as well. A simple way to do this is with a 555 timer.

A question like this has already been asked before:
[What is the simplest way to generate PWM without a Microcontroller?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/32533/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-generate-pwm-without-a-microcontroller)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm struggling to know how to actually hook up everything

Comment: There are a lot of suggestions that I have researched, maybe I am making a fuss out of something so simple