# How to use extra channels in drone controller for other purpose

Tags: drone, quad-copter, uav

I'm doing a **hexacopter** for my academic project. I brought **flysky fs-ct6b** drone controller. It has 6 channels. 4 channels is enough for controlling the drone. but I don't know how to use another extra 2 channels for other purposes. i.e for on/off a pump for the sprayer within the drone. can u help me, please?

Comment: This isn't really an electrical engineering question, but rather a question about usage of an RC receiver. A common usage is a servo motor controlled by each channel. It's really up to you what you connect to it and how your RF controller represents that channel. Try searching for "rc hobby forum" and you may get more traction there.

Comment: additional impellers for horizontal propulsion? A winch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 6 connecters on the receiver have 3 pins each. +5v Signal Gnd

The signal is an output that is Pulse Width Modulated PWM / Pulse-Position Modulation PPM. Such that it pulses on to 5v and back off to 0v(GND) at a frequency 50hz with a pulse on the duration of between 1ms and 2ms with the length indicating what the value of the signal sent from the transmitter is.

[How to get the PWM frequency and duration of each pulse?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/129961/how-to-get-the-pwm-frequency-and-duration-of-each-pulse)
https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/hobby-servo-tutorial/all