# What are the main ways to generate a pwm?

Tags: pwm

Let's suppose to use PWM (e.g.  to control the 'speed' of a motor)

What would be the possible way to generate a PWM signal?

On the one extreme, there is pure software techniques where 'a programmer typically writes a value to a memory-mapped register to set the duty cycle' [Lee & Seshia, Introduction to Embedded Systems]. On the other extreme, there is dedicated PWM Peripheral. What are the other ways to genrate a PWM?

Comment: 'write a value to a register' is a terrible answer. I hope that textbook explains what that register does with that value.

Comment: is this a school assignment question?

Comment: Before asking a question on here, I _highly_ advise you to look on this website and seeing if someone else has asked the same thing. For instance: [What is the simplest way to generate PWM without a Microcontroller?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/32533/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-generate-pwm-without-a-microcontroller) is a question that can help you. I know, there are times where I think to myself, "There's no way someone has asked this question on this website." Turns out that I'm wrong 95% of the time when I want to ask a question.

Comment: two other ways are with an oscillator (like 555) and with phase-control (like light dimmers)